# Installing a NAS server with multiple hard drives

Tags: server, partitioning, hard-drive, nas

I am setting up a NAS server hopefully with a ZFS file system. I have a question I haven't been able to find a straightforward answer to online. I am plaining to have my main OS on a 60gb ssd, I have 4 other 2 TB HHD. When I am installing the OS is it necessary to have all 4 hard drives plugged into SATA? Can I just install the base server and after I am done building plugged in thoes HHDs and configure them? if so how do I go about doing that. And if not what is the best recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do that.  After the server is up and running on the single hard drive, install the others using [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive).

The tl;dr version is that you create a mount point for each drive and update `/etc/fstab` to mount the new drives.

Comment: thank you! this there a recommended way?

Comment: That is the official documentation.